# HTML Form: Datalist Option Tag Text is not showing in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-select, datalist

I am working in a HTML Form. I added some HTML tags including Datalist. In datalist I want to show suggestion to user with different text and want to send the different value to server.

As you can see the below image that I found on Google like datalist works like this means showing Value in left and Text in right but now its not working.
[image]

```
<input list="some-list">
<datalist id="some-list">
  <option value="first_value">Some Description</option>
  <option value="another_value">Another Thing Here</option>
  <option value="first_second_third">More Stuff</option>
</datalist>
```

You can see a simple live [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kjx4f2se/) where you can text it on Chrome Updated Version Browser.

The code is working on Edge, Firefox, Avast Secure Browser, Opera, IE11 but not on Chrome. **My question is simple Why it is not working as shown in Pic in Chrome now?**

Comment: My question is about Chrome Problem not Datalist styling as shared in the above links. My question is that now Chrome i not showing the Text Value as it does previously. Why?.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling / updating Chrome? ,

Comment: I am also facing the same issue ... seems issue raised in latest chrome version 73 instead option text its showing option value in datalist. I hope google will provide the fix soon.

Comment: @Ernie I tried everything on Chrome. Uninstalling, Reinstalling, Updating etc. Still have the bug.

Comment: @PSrinivasGoud Yes. I also feel that its a Bug as I tested in on my PC, Laptop etc but Latest Chrome is not showing the required format.

Comment: It's a bug of Chrome's new release. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55383145/4271117

Comment: It worked fine about a month ago... I hope they will fix it, it was quite useful.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Please update to latest chrome and check. Now its working as expected.

Comment: Someone please add it in Answer so I will close this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update to latest chrome and check. its chrome browser bug.

Answer (score -3):

```
<input type="text" list="some-list">
<datalist id="some-list">
 <option value="first_value">Some Description</option>
 <option value="another_value">Another Thing Here</option>
 <option value="first_second_third">More Stuff </option>
</datalist>
```